How to view images in Windows Terminal?
Viewing images in terminal is something that can be quite convenient, however, Windows Terminal is no Kitty terminal, unfortunately. Prerequisites to easily resolve this particular dilemma: WSL installed. Preferred Linux distribution installed.

Launch preferred/installed Linux distro via WSL:
wsl -d kali-linux

Install timg:
sudo apt install timg

To avoid resulting pixelated image displays, specify the Sixel protocol:
timg -p 's' *jpg

Voilà. I am now viewing all my jpg images.
Tip: For a more concise view, use a grid to create a contact sheet:
timg --grid=3x2 -p 's' *png


Yep, this is all you need to know. Windows Terminal has supported sixel images since 1.22:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-22-release/
